# For every interval $(a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ there exists a dyadic rational interval contained in $(a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers

Let $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that there exist $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\left(\frac{m-1}{2^j},\frac{m}{2^j}\right]\subset(a,b].$$
We know that there exists $j\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$ such that $1/2^j<b-a$. Let $k:=\max\{\ell\in\mathbb{Z}\ |\ \ell/2^j\leq a\}$ and $n:=\min\{\ell\in\mathbb{Z}\ |\ b\leq \ell/2^j\}$. Then
$$\frac{k}{2^j}\leq a<\frac{k+1}{2^j}\leq b\text{ and }a<\frac{n-1}{2^j}<b\leq\frac{n}{2^j}.$$
I'm not able to show that either $(k+2)/2^j\leq b$ or $a<(n-2)/2^j$. Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548212/infinite-dyadic-rationals-in-any-open-interval-a-b-where-ab-in-mathbbr

Comment: @Henry I looked at that question, but it seems that that procedure allows you to find arbitrary dyadic rationals between $a$ and $b$, whereas I want dyadic rationals such that the numerators are successive integers. Am I missing something?

Comment: The numerators of dyadic rationals (other than integers) in lowest terms are always odd  and so not successive.  But  if what you want does not require lowest terms, take any two distinct dyadic rationals in the interval, write them both with a common denominator, and then if necessary find the others with that denominator between them so you can choose a successive pair.

Comment: Notice that there exists an $n$ such that $2^n(b-a) \ge 3.$ Then $m = \lfloor 2^n b\rfloor$ and $j = n$ should do the trick.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks!